# How to use the Anaconda environment on blender at linux?

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I'm having problems to use some modes like numpy and pandas on blender, apparently the blender's python do not allow us to install packages using pip; so I thought that I could resolve this issue changing its environment to the Anaconda or something like that. I looked for solutions, but all I founded worked on windows but I use ubuntu. If someone can help me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Using Anaconda in Blender](https://janakiev.com/blog/using-anaconda-in-blender/)

1. Install Anaconda and Blender
2. Use Anaconda to create a python installation.  The article doesn't mention but the installation has to match the version of Python used by the version of Blender.  In the case of Blender 2.93 and 3.0, it's Python 3.9.
3. Rename the Blender installation's Python directory.  (Don't delete it in case something goes wrong and you need to get back to it.)
4. Link your Anaconda installed Python into your Blender installation where the Python directory should be.

Test this by using the Blender python console and trying to import bpy and some Anaconda managed package.

Comment: note on linux to create a symbolic link you need to use another method than windows eg https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/

Comment: also on Linux you can use a hard link, but I don't think that's a good idea.